# PHP Regex moving selection to different location in string

Tags: php, regex

I currently have this regex:

```
$text = preg_replace("#<sup>(?:(?!</?sup).)*$key(?:(?!</?sup).)*<\/sup>#is", '<sup>'.$val.'</sup>', $text);
```

The objective of the regex is to take `<sup>[stuff here]$key[stuff here]</sup>` and remove the stuff within the `[stuff here]` locations.

What I actually would like to do, is not remove `$key[stuff here]</sup>`, but simply move the stuff to `$key</sup>[stuff here]`

I've tried using `$1-$4` and `\\1-\\4` and I can't seem to get the text to be added after `</sup>`

Comment: Do not use regexp with HTML !

Comment: That has been highly debatable here. But, as it shows, in some cases, regex is appropriate, even for HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
$text = preg_replace(
  '#<sup>((?:(?!</?sup).)*)'.$key.'((?:(?!</?sup).)*)</sup>#is', 
  '<sup>'.$val.'</sup>\1\2', 
  $text
);
```

The (?:...)* bit isn't actually a sub-pattern, and is therefor not available using backreferences. Also, if you use ' rather than " for string literals, you will only need to escape \ and '

// Cheers, Morten

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine preg_match(); and preg_replace();

1. You match the desired stuff with preg_match() and store in to the variable.
2. You replace with the same regex to empty string.
3. Append the variable you store to at the end.